# global variable to be shared in multiple on() function

Tags: jquery

how to set x to gobal variable in my case?

```
$(document).on( 'click', '#something', function (){
   x = $(#etc);
});


$(document).on( 'click', '#somethingElse', function (){

 alert(x) <-- unidentified here 

});
```

even if I bind two on() together, x is still 'unpassable'

Comment: can you share the html also... which of these 2 is fired first

Comment: no html needed I guess? the first one fire first

Comment: Do you declare `x` anywhere?

Comment: @MerraleeMandel not in this case http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2XFW5/1/

Comment: your code works, see:: http://jsfiddle.net/sfg2W/

Comment: @Musa if `x` was not declared then an `reference` error should have come right

Comment: your code should work, if #something else clicked 1-st, x become global if not declared using var

Comment: My assumption is `x` is declared but the `somethingElse` handler is fired first... or there is a local instance of `x` in the scope of `somethingElse` handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x;

$(document).on( 'click', '#something', function (){
   x = $('#etc');
});


$(document).on( 'click', '#somethingElse', function (){

 alert(x);

});

</script>
```

example : http://jsfiddle.net/2wS4k/

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare `x` as global variable. So, It can be alter/declared from any of the functions.

```
var x;
$(document).on( 'click', '#something', ...
$(document).on( 'click', '#somethingElse', ...
```

And you have to pass selector as string:

```
$("#etc") // not $(#etc)
```

Comment: While it's a good idea, it's not required. Unless you declare it as a local variable, it's automatically treated as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do also something like this :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var Test = {

        init:function() {

             $(document).on( 'click', '#something', function (){
                 Test.x = $('#etc');
             });


             $(document).on( 'click', '#somethingElse', function (){

             alert(Test.x);

             });
        }

    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        Test.init();
    });

    </script>
```